# Migrating an iOS application using Cocoapods 1.0.1 from Swift 2.2 to 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift3, xcode8

I'm currently upgrading an iOS app from Swift 2.2 to 3.0.  I have pointed all of my pod dependencies to their Swift 3 versions and have migrated my code.  However, when I run `pod install` and try to open my Workspace, Xcode still wants me to convert the "Pods" project to the latest Swift syntax:

> The project "Pods" has targets that contain source code developed with an earlier version of Swift.

[image: Convert to Current Swift Syntax]

But I've already upgraded my dependencies to their Swift 3.0 versions.  What gives?

<sup>(This is a canonical Q&A pair to help future users who encounter this issue)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue with Cocoapods 1.0.1 where I needed to manually specify the `SWIFT_VERSION` of the installed targets to be 3.0:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```

My complete `Podfile` (for a test/development pod):

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
  pod "MyPod", :path => "../"
end

target 'MyApp_Tests' do
  pod "MyPod", :path => "../"  
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Issue [#5521 - Compiler Version for Xcode 8](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5521) helped find this workaround.

Comment: @JonShier do I have to subscribe to a specific beta channel to get release candidate versions?  I didn't see that with a normal "`pod update`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using their release candidate version

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Then do a pod install again

Comment: Right, but if you're on a team that is not supporting pre-release and release candidates versions of Cocoapods (and are stuck on 1.0.1), this isn't a viable solution.

Comment: Use Swift Package Manager instead?